# Please help - error on Facebook when trying to post my website

Tags: facebook

I just built my website www.angelaarno.com on wix (hosted on ipage). I'm really not a developer (obviously). But site suits my needs. I want to post a link to my site on my facebook page, but when I try I get this error message:

Could not post to timeline. The privacy settings for this attachment prevent you from posting it to this Timeline.

I ran debugger on facebook to try to identify/fix the issue. Here's the link.

No clue how to fix this problem. Anyone out there that can help a totally clueless nubie?

Thanks
Angela

Comment: Well, you can see from the report that the debugger gives out that you have made a mistake in the `fb:admins` element. You have placed your username but it expects a user id... See if that solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It allows me to access your site, and post it on social media. I registered my site under private (which you can't fix), but luckily you do not have that problem. If you personally can not post the link, try sending it to some close friends and having them post it. Not only will it get the word out, it will also help your credibility.